# Shapes on different windows?

Tags: python, tkinter

With the project I'm doing, I need `tableone` to appear only on `floorplan` and not on any other windows. The error that turns up is an attribute error that says `'int' object has no attribute '_create'` . As someone who is newer to tkinter, I'm not sure how I fix this. What I'm expecting the code to do is when `button1` (with the text "floor plan") is pressed, a separate window should open with a silver rectangle that turns gray when the user hovers over it and prints "clicked" when the user clicks the rectangle '`tableone`'

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title("Main window")
root.geometry("1366x768")
canvas-Canvas(root, width=1366, height=768)

#make sure table buttons work
def clicked(*args):
    print("clicked")

def create_floorplan():
    global floorplan
    floorplan = Toplevel()
    floorplan.title("Floor plan")
    floorplan.geometry("1366x768")
    tableone=Canvas.create_rectangle(75, 55, 195, 105, fill="silver", activefill="gray", tags="tableone")
    tableone=Canvas.create_text(137, 80, text="1", font=("Helvetica", 20), fill="white", tags="tableone")
    canvas.tag_bind("tableone","<Button-1>", clicked)
    
    #button just to see if it turns up on window
    testbutton=Button(floorplan, text="test")
    testbutton.place(x=10, y=10)


button1=Button(root, text="floor plan", command=create_floorplan)
button1.place(x=10, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

The issue does seem to be when I try to implement `tableone` as when I comment out

```
    tableone=Canvas.create_text(137, 80, text="1", font=("Helvetica", 20), fill="white", tags="tableone")
    canvas.tag_bind("tableone","<Button-1>", clicked)
```

it doesn't show any errors and the button `testbutton` is present.

I hope that all makes sense, if not I can try and explain the problem again. Many thanks in advance and really appreciate any advice anyone can give!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces that error so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: You have to think about who owns what.  If you want multiple floorplans, then don't use `global`.  Also, you've created your `canvas` on the root window.  If you want the canvas to be on the floorplan, then create another canvas in `create_floorplan`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what you want.  Note how I only create the entities with the proper "parent" objects.  Also note the "canvas.pack()", which is the reason you never saw your canvas.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title("Main window")
root.geometry("1366x768")

#make sure table buttons work
def clicked(*args):
    print("clicked")

def create_floorplan():
    floorplan = Toplevel()
    floorplan.title("Floor plan")
    floorplan.geometry("1366x768")
    canvas=Canvas(floorplan, width=1000, height=700)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_rectangle(75, 55, 195, 105, fill="silver", activefill="gray", tags="tableone")
    canvas.create_text(137, 80, text="1", font=("Helvetica", 20), fill="white")
    canvas.tag_bind("tableone","<Button-1>", clicked)
    
    testbutton=Button(floorplan, text="test")
    testbutton.place(x=10, y=10)

button1=Button(root, text="floor plan", command=create_floorplan)
button1.place(x=10, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This worked!! I completely forgot about `canvas.pack()` and it would not have even crossed my mind to do what you've done here. Thank you!!